# How do you get CommandParameter working for a MenuItem in a ContextMenu using a property from the parent Button?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**Result**
I figured out what was going on for myself. I had kind of a weird combination of things, so this may or may not be useful to someone else.

I'll go ahead and document the solution in an answer entry. My solution involves a small amount of code-behind. I'm not generally a fan of code-behind. It's only view-related, so doesn't break MVVM, though. If someone gives me a XAML-only solution that isn't too far out, I'll gladly use that as the accepted answer.

**Problem**
I have a WPF app (.NET6) that has a grid of images that represent discreet objects. I want each to have an identical context menu. Each one needs to send a unique `CommandParameter` so that the view-model can identify which object to operate on.

In order to give myself a way to add the identifier, I subclassed Button like this:

```
public class PartButton : Button
{
    public int PartPosition { get; set; }
}
```

I'm aware of the issue regarding a context menu not being in the visual tree, and thus not inheriting the `DataContext` from the top level control (`UserControl` in this case). The trick is usually just to use `PlacementTarget` to get the parent, and use its `DataContext`.

It was also a goal to have a left-click work as well as a right-click. To do that, I used a `RoutedEvent` for `Click` and used a `Storyboard` to set `ContextMenu.IsOpen` to `true` on the button. If you're more experienced with XAML, you might already see the problem.

Because there are 30 buttons, the ultimate goal was to add the menu through a style so that the button could be declared using as little code as possible.. Just to get one working, I tried it like this:

```
<jb:PartButton
    Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
    IsEnabled="{ Binding Path=PartStatuses[1] }"
    PartPosition="1">
    <Image Source="../Resources/Part.png" />
    <jb:PartButton.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem Header="Test Part"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PartPosition}"
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Proxy}, Path=Data.TestPartCmd}"
                />
        </ContextMenu>
    </jb:PartButton.ContextMenu>
</jb:PartButton>
```

That works fine for a right-click. However, when using the `RoutedEvent` trick above, left-click results in `PlacementTarget` always being `null`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my site, works as expected, command parameter is passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, here is my current solution:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Bootloader Test"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.PartPosition, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
        Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.BootloaderTestCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
        />
```

To work, it needs this code-behind:

```
public void OnPartButtonPressed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button btn)
    {
        btn.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = btn;
        btn.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

As it sits, this is now fully implemented as a style so that all that's really needed for each button is something like this:

```
<jb:PartButton
    PartPosition="1"
    Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" />
```

In the real project, I also declare the image for the button at the object because I was struggling with getting that done via a style. The image depends on an index (`PartPosition`) that has to be resolved in the view-model. It's hard to use a style to get a property from the view-model using a value that has to be queried from the object. Different problem, though, and something I may or may not worry about later.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Test Part" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Command="{Binding TestPartCmd}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
```

and ViewModel like this

```
    public RelayCommand<System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem> TestPartCmd
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem>((menuItem) =>
            {
                int partPosition = ((PartButton)((System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup)((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)menuItem.Parent).Parent).PlacementTarget).PartPosition;
            });
        }
    }
```

There may be a better way, but I haven't thought of it yet。

Comment: That just breaks MVVM too much. Before I'd do this, I'd just write a custom control. Thanks for trying, though.